# Sqlite > single column with multiple values

Tags: php, sqlite

What is the right way to use multiple values in a single cell in a sql database.
I m trying to write a code for visitor tracking, this is what i m trying to track

IP1: index.php
     contact.php
     sssa.php
IP2: aaduau.php
     ssssau.php
and so on

I want to insert different page names for one IP address. What is the right algorithm to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would actually suggest using two columns in the table: `ip_address`, `page_name`.

When inserting, you would do something similar to:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$page = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
mysql_query('INSERT INTO logs (ip_address, page_name) VALUES(INET_ATON("' . $ip . '"), "' . $page . '");');
```

To pull all records by IP, you would just use:

```
$results = mysql_query('SELECT page_name FROM logs WHERE ip_address=INET_ATON("' . $ip . '");');
```

[`INET_ATON()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) is used to convert the IP-address `string` into a network address, or `long`. To convert back, you can use [`INET_NTOA()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa), such as `SELECT NTOA(ip_address) AS ip_address FROM logs;`

Answer (score 0):

Add commas ',' without quotes to save your pages name in a single cell and while retrieving the data back from database use PHP explode() function to explode the string.